# What are the alternatives for TinyMCE getContent and setContent functions for Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

Using TinyMCE editor, we used getContent() and setContent() JS functions to get the contents of the editor and set it

What are the alternatives for them using Gutenberg?

Answer (score 0):

Here are what worked for me after some struggle to find a working solution

to get the content

```
wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'content' );
```

To set the content

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( { content: editedContent } );
parsedBlocks = wp.blocks.parse(wp.data.select( "core/editor" ).getEditedPostContent());
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).resetBlocks([]);
wp.data.dispatch( "core/editor" ).insertBlocks( parsedBlocks );
```

It will remove the current blocks and insert new parsed blocks. Possible there is a better solution while I still don't know it